# Ошибка при загрузке webpacka и когда запускаешь команду npm start

Tags: npm, webpack

При загрузке webpacka и когда запускаю команду `npm start`, получаю ошибку:

> Bus error (core dumped)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 135
>   npm ERR! react-boilerplate@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 135
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the react-boilerplate@1.0.0 start script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /home/zhanelya/.npm/_logs/2017-07-05T05_40_06_432Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

проблема решается менеджером пакетов nvm

проблема была в ос linux ubuntu. `npm` почему то запрашивал права `root`, и приходилось запускать через `sudo npm start`. Помог `node version manager` сокращенно `nvm`. 
как установить `nvm` можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-for-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/).

Comment: Не могли бы Вы дать более подробный ответ? Спасибо.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ни вопроса ни ответа... Сам танцую сам пою...